# Non-blocking Java methods

Tags: java

Suppose I want to make a method non-blocking, and make the app continue as it is and still surely get the return value:

```
Key key = datastore.put(complexInstance);
String name = key.getName();
doSomethingWithTheName(name);
```

Or simply, for some Java environment that can't run thread for more than 30 seconds.

Where in the put method:

```
public Key put(Object instance){
  Key result = null;
  // In here process could take up time, say 30 seconds or more, IDK :-/
  return result; 
}
```

What is the strategy to achieve this?

Comment: You edited your question and removed method "sendTheKeyToTheUI(key)" completely after i gave the answer, making it look irrelevant. There is way edit questions and this is wrong approach.

Comment: The way your latest edit puts it, I think you are asking magic. Your `put` is expected to take 30 seconds, but `doSomethingWithTheName` is supposed to run immediately, although the name depends on the 30 seconds computation. This requires a crystal ball :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an implementation of an ExecutorService in combination with a Future object (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). You would simply start a new thread (or use an existing one) and could fetch the result later.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 made the process a lot simpler:

```
//field in a manager class
ScheduledExecutorService es = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

//Schedule a task
es.schedule(() -> { /* contents of a runnable */ }, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Otherwise, you can still just use an anonymous runnable with the Scheduler:

```
es.schedule(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        /* do what you need */
    }

}, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, as you specified, you will still need to do something for a returned value. There isn't really much that you can do, aside from use something from either a state manager, or to execute relevant methods within your runnable.

Comment: Pedantic, but use `submit`, not schedule. OP didn't indicate any need for a "Scheduled" Executor service.

Comment: also need to solve the problem of returning a promise on completion.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to take a thread pool, probably via the interface `ExecutorService`, that the methods will run on. You could make it a `private static` variable, but more likely it's better for it to be passed in or at least configured by the client code, who will set size, etc.

Note that if IO is the asynchronous part, it's better to use something built on Java's nio framework than to use lots of threads.

You will need to return a `Future` of some sort. Through Java 7 at least (I'm not sure about 8), Java's future library is very weak and omits some obviously needed functionality. Look at either [Functional Java](http://www.functionaljava.org/) or Google's library. But you will notice that many libraries (Apache's MINA, Amazon Web Service's Java SDK, etc.) implement their own promise libraries to get over these weaknesses. (I did the same in my company's code base. Whoops.)